# Laravel perfect version for beginners?

Tags: laravel

As I am new with Laravel and there are already many versions out there I'm confused about which version I should start with? Which will be the perfect version to start?

Versions are: 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.4.22 and upcoming 5.5

It will be my pleasure if Laravel experts give me some good advice.

Comment: 5.3 is perfect and reliable enough for you

Comment: Latest stable so 5.4. Why learn old stuff ?

Comment: off-topic question.  I didn't downvote though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with laravel 5.4 and start working with PHP 7. There's no point in learning the older versions at the moment. With 5.5 (LTS) set to release in July, you will be well set with learning 5.4 now.

There are already tons of resources for 5.4 and any and most codes and tutorials that uses 5.3 can be used with 5.4 without any/much change.

A good series to get started.

https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017

Comment: Thank You My Dear Friend  :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to this URL: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017. It's version 5.4, by far the best resource you'll find for laravel. And it's free.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with Laravel 5.4 because Laravel 5.4 is updated one if learn Laravel 5.3 then you definitely learn 5.4 therefore you start with Laravel 5.4

Thank you